# Package name of current running application package name Android 6.0

Tags: android, package-managers, custom-keyboard

I am using custom keyboard to share image to any app like Facebook,whatsApp and i want to know  the current open application package name on onIteamClickListener of my custom keyboard to share data without chooser dialog. 
Below is my code

```
grdPhoto.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            String packageName = tasks.get(1).processName;


               }
    });
```

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
 packageInfo=mActivity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mActivity.getPack
    ageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
```

Comment: Hi Chandrakant,
Thanks for reply. Actuall i want to create custom keyboard to share data to any application so i need package name of that application in which my custom keyboard is open. Your code returns the my custom keyboard package name but i want to package name of that application in which my keyboard is open.